# Types are erased before run time

Tags: types, compilation, type-erasure, agda, type-theory

I know for sure that in Haskell types are always    erased  before  run-time. What happen in case of Agda?

Is dependent type information carried through to run-time ?

Comment: I'm not sure what Agda does but Idris tries to throw away as much as it possibly can. I'm not sure about Agda but it would be strictly a good thing to do as much as possible I'd say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What runtime? There are at least four backends: those which target GHC (called MAlonzo), UHC, Epic and JavaScript. Some initial details can be found in [the Agda wiki](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.Compilation): you can read how the Epic backend erases types there or in this [paper](http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/146807.pdf) (the "3.3 Erasure" chapter). In short, the Epic and the UHC backends erase all types that a fully applied function receives, but doesn't perform full erasure as it can change the semantics of a program (quoted from a [paper](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~swier004/Publications/UtrechtAgdaCompiler.pdf) about the UHC backend):

> Type translation
>
> The remaining terms `Π`, `Set` and `Level` are
>   significant for type checking only. In Agda, a value of type `Set` or
>   `Level` cannot be inspected or pattern matched. As Agda enforces that
>   it is impossible to observe any value of these types, they cannot
>   affect the runtime semantics. For executing a program, it is thus safe
>   to replace all occurrences of such values by the unit value `⊤`.
>
> One could also be tempted to completely remove any values of these
>   kind. This could potentially alter the semantics of the translated
>   program. Agda does not evaluate expressions under lambdas; dropping
>   lambda abstractions taking type expressions could remove
>   evaluation-blocking lambdas. A partial erasure of types is possible in
>   a sound way. Saturated function applications for example can always be
>   optimized in this way. A more detailed description of when such types
>   may be soundly erased can be found in previous work by Letouzey.